# Can I use a variable value as a string delimiter in batch for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Is there a way in windows batch scripting to use a variable value as a string delimiter? 
I want to "cut" a string in two by a number that varies for each line. i.e.

NNNN

I want to create a string of only

NNNN

I have %%M set to the number NNNN, but a for loop extracting the right bits isn't working, it is actuall cutting on the letter "M", not value of %%M. How to do this in batch?

```
                FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims**=%%M"** %%X IN ("%%F") DO (
                    SET /A LINE="%%M %%Y"
```

Comment: 1) is your `%%M` a variable of another `for`loop or simply a variable? 2) a delimiter is a single char only, not a string.

Comment: moreover that what dbenham says you cannot use a for loop parameter _before_ it exists.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to provide some examples of what you want to do, a way could be found.

Answer (score 2):

You ***cannot*** use a FOR variable (`%%M`), or delayed expansion (`!var1!`) within a FOR option. You ***can*** use normal expansion (`%var%`), but that will not work if `%var%` is used within the same block that defined the variable. Since you want to use `%%M`, it won't do any good to define a variable and use `%var%`.

The solution is to CALL a procedure and transfer the `%%M` value to a CALL argument. It looks like you will need to pass the `%%F` value as well