# For-loop not stripping semi-colon (;) and also breaks with bar(|) as %variable%, but works as intended with other symbols (/\?^$%*=#,.:etc) in batch

Tags: for-loop, variables, batch-file, cmd, delimiter

While working on a script that uses a kind of self-setting delimiter based on input, I discovered a bit of a curiousity with semi-colons injected into `for` parameters as a %variable%.

There is surprisingly little it seems on setting the `for /F "delims=...` as a variable.
Just this lone question and single answer from [March, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29154820/21430468).  However from what little there was, using a combination of a `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` and some (as described in another answer) *waton abuse* of a `for` loop and `endlocal & set...` I was able to get my delims to populate (Only challanged by `!%str%:~0,1!` which blanks versus `!%~1:~0,1!`) with normal expansion into the main loop.  And this works well, with exceptions...

Bar delimiters obviously break things.  I've experimented, but without breaking everything else by changing counts leading into the main loop, I cannot seem to accomdate for them to work.  This is trivial, however I can't help but feel a solution here is a solution for the another problematic symbol, the semi-colon.

Semi-colons are an odd duck.  With `@ECHO ON` they seem to populate the `delims=%delim%`correctly, but don't strip and break delimitation, even with`eol=` .  Weirder yet, if explicitly set as `"eol= delims=;"`, semi-colons work entirely as expected.

While semi-colons aren't a necessity, I can't help but feel a few steps from now they might be.  Even with many alternatives, this leaves me very curious what's going on and if it can be worked around without many additional lines of code, pretending for a minute semi-colons were critical for later function.

The script is below. It contains some examples for readline input, the expected output, and notes about results for ease of debugging. Readline input can be set directly, or during execution (depending on personal RL history prefs).

```
@ECHO OFF
@set ESC=

setLocal
if "%*" == "" (set /P strInput=Input parameters:) else set "strInput=%*"
call :delimVars strInput
endLocal
exit /B

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:delimVars [[delim]value str]...
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: input: ?~delim So long world ?~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: /~delim So long world /~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: \~delim So long world \~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: ^~delim So long world ^~delim Goodbye universe Hello multiverse
:::::::::::: ^ strips w/ interesting side effects
:: input: $~delim So long world$~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse %=(strips)=%
:: input: %%~delim So long world%%~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse   %=(strips)=%
:: input: ^~delim So long world ^~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: *~delim So long world *~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: =~delim So long world =~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: #~delim So long world #~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: ,~delim So long world ,~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: '~delim So long world '~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: :~delim So long world :~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(strips)=%
:: input: |~delim So long world |~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(breaks)=%
:::::::::::: uncertain how to escape w/o impacting parsing of other symbols
:: input: ;~delim So long world ;~delim Goodbye universe ^& Hello multiverse    %=(sticks)=%
:::::::::::: unique behaviour of semi-colon breaks delimination, even with "eol= "
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

setLocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~1"
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%X in ("!%~1:~0,1!") do (   %=(Param var Expansion must be used, str var blanks)=%
endLocal
set "delim=%%~X"
)
:delimVars_loop
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
REM for /F "eol= tokens=1,* delims=;" %%A in ("!%str%!") do (       %=(Semi-colons strip)=%
for /F "eol= tokens=1,* delims=%delim%" %%A in ("!%str%!") do (     %=(Semi-colons stick)=%
    for /F "eol= tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ("%%A") do (
        endLocal
        set "val="%%~a" "%%~b""
        )
    )
)
echo;%val%
set str=
set val=
set delim=
endLocal
exit /B
```

Comment: The expected output would be: 
`"~delims" "So long world "`
Keyboard issues have had some interesting effects if left unattended. Apologies.